# Is the collection in tensorflow.get_collection() cleared?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm learning about neural nets using Tensorflow through the Stanford course. I found this while implementing a RNN and did not quite understand why the losses are accumulated:

```python
# This adds a loss operation to the Graph for batch training
def add_loss_op(self, output):
    all_ones = [tf.ones([self.config.batch_size * self.config.num_steps])]
    cross_entropy = sequence_loss(
        [output], [tf.reshape(self.labels_placeholder, [-1])], all_ones, len(self.vocab))
    tf.add_to_collection('total_loss', cross_entropy)
    # Doesn't this increase in size every batch of training?
    loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('total_loss')) 
    return loss
```

The documentation for `get_collection()`  [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.get_collection) doesn't mention anything about clearing the variables. Since this is run for every training step, are the losses incremented every epoch / minibatch of training and carried over?

I am still new to NNs so do correct any misunderstanding I have on this!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the add_n here is actually just to make sure that any pre-existing losses in the 'total_loss' collection get added in for the final result. It's not changing any variables, just summing up its inputs and returning the total.

Answer (score 1):

If I not guess wrong, before this add_loss_to_collection op, there are other ops which add l2_loss of trainable vars to this collection. If it did, this add_n op means sum up all losses(including l2_loss and prediction loss) in this "loss" collection. You get confused in "there are many iterations to run add_to_loss operation, is the loss increment?",  No, if you debug the run process, you will see that this collection size has been certained when the whole Graph is building, when tensorflow run the in real, the size or the framework of that collection not changed.